# How to effectively remove immediate tags in XML String in Java

Tags: java, xml, string, xml-parsing

I have a XML being parsed as string.. the basic structure is something as below

```
 <envelope>
    <body>
        <entity1>
                <tag1>
                 .
                 .
                </tag 1>
                <tag2>
                 .
                 .
               </tag2>
        </entity1>
        <entity 2>
               <tag1>
                 .
                 .
               </tag1>
               <tag2>
                 .
                 .
               </tag2>
        </entity2>
```

I need to remove the tags lets say tag2 i.e. the whole  ..  block.
I am doing this using a while loop, something like

```
 while(str.indexOf("<tag2>")>=0)
    {
       strRepl=str.substring(str.indexOf("<tag2>"),str.indexOf("</tag2>")+7);
       str=xmlString.replaceFirst(strRepl,"");
    }
```

This is working but i wanted to understand if there is a better way to implement this using strings?
Please suggest.

Comment: Why not use an XML parser to parse XML?

Comment: Actually the logic needs to go inside Clover ETL tool transform component , by default it doesn't support XML parser. So wanted to implement through String

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Regex for that. Java provides Pattern and Matcher class that could do the job for you.

```
    String yourString = "<envelope><body><entity1></entity1></body></envelope>";
    String REGULAR_EXPRESSION= "(\\<body>.+?\\</body>)";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REGULAR_EXPRESSION, Pattern.DOTALL | Pattern.MULTILINE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(hello);
    if (matcher.find()) {
       System.out.println(yourString.replaceAll(matcher.group(1), ""));
    }
```

Here `(\\<body>.+?\\</body>)` represents all the content enclosed inside `<body>` tag inclusive of tag. 
The line `matcher.group(1)`represent the position of the matched string.

if you want to replace all the occurrence simply use

```
    yourString = matcher.replaceAll("");
```

And to replace first occurrence only use :

```
    yourString = matcher.replaceFirst("");
```

And i am not sure whether it will work for the new line "\n" content in the string, if the string is of single line , you can use :

```
System.out.println(yourString.replaceAll(REGULAR_EXPRESSION, ""));
```

Comment: From above i understand , i can check for a pattern and subsequently remove it.
However, my requirement is to remove the whole tag.. i.e. for example everything between <tag2> and </tag2> including the tags.

Comment: @VarunKashyap yes exactly (\\<tag2>.+?\\</tag2>) in first example , do the functionlaity for you. Try that out.

Comment: it will remove not only the tag but the content too.

Comment: Thanks Pawal ..
yes i tried in similar fashion.. something like 
xmlString = replace(xmlString,'(?s)<tag2>.*?</tag2>','');
This works fine for me.. thanks for the input on regex..